# Do empty braces call the default constructor or the constructor taking an std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregate-initialization

The following is a quote from **Effective Modern C++** (page 55):

> "Suppose that you use an empty set of braces to construct an object that supports default constructor and also supports std::initializer_list construction. What do your empty braces mean? etc. The rule is that you get default construction."

I tried this with std::array:

```
std::array<int, 10> arr{};
```

and got the warning from g++ (version 4.8.2):

> warning: missing initializer for member ‘std::array<int, 10ul>::_M_elems’

which is the warning one gets when trying to construct an `std::array` from an empty `std::initializer_list` (see [Why can I initialize a regular array from {}, but not a std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271975/why-can-i-initialize-a-regular-array-from-but-not-a-stdarray) for a discussion of this warning).

So, why isn't the above line of code interpreted as calling the default constructor?

Comment: `std::array` has no constructor taking an `std::initializer_list`, and the initializer you have here isn't an `std::initailizer_list` either. It's referred to as a braced-init-list. I'm not sure why you're getting a warning, as using empty braces should value-initialize the nested array.

Comment: @0x499602D2 see my answer to the linked question, gcc was being aggressive and later versions of gcc do not produce the warning.

Comment: Also note that they changed the C++11 standard in a significant way in a DR. The actual standard says one thing, but compilers are expected to do something completely different.

Comment: @o11c which DR are you referring to? It is not clear to me which behavior you are referring to.

Answer (score 8):

That is because [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is an aggregate and therefore [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is performed this is covered in the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `8.5.4` *[dcl.init.list]* which says:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is
>     value-initialized.
> - Otherwise, if T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
>
>   ```
>   double ad[] = { 1, 2.0 }; // OK
>   int ai[] = { 1, 2.0 }; // error: narrowing
>
>   struct S2 {
>     int m1;
>     double m2, m3;
>   };
>
>   S2 s21 = { 1, 2, 3.0 }; // OK
>   S2 s22 { 1.0, 2, 3 }; // error: narrowing
>   S2 s23 { }; // OK: default to 0,0,0
>   ```

and we can see if it is not an aggregate then the list goes on and says:

> - Otherwise, if T is a specialization of std::initializer_list, an initializer_list object is
>     constructed as described below and used to initialize the object according to the rules for initialization
>     of an object from a class of the same type (8.5).
> - Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated
>     and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing conversion (see
>     below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

We can confirm `std::array` is an aggregate from section `23.3.2.1` *[array.overview]*:

> An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the
>   syntax
>
> ```
> array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };
> ```
>
> where initializer-list is a comma-separated list of up to N elements
>   whose types are convertible to T.

section `8.5.1` referenced is `8.5.1` Aggregates *[dcl.init.aggr]* and says:

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified
>   in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken as
>   initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript
>   or member order [...]

and we come full-circle back to section `8.5.4` which is where we started.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the standard document that you quoted (if it is freely accessible, of course)?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg done added link into the answer, you can see [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) which lists all the drafts available to the public.